# How to get object from re.compile that matched, but not the match group

Tags: python

Likely a confusing title, so let me explain..

```
import re
fruit_list = ['apples', 'banana', 'peach', 'plum', 'pineapple', 'kiwi']
myfavourite = 'Apples are really nice'
fruit_compile = re.compile('|'.join(fruit_list),flags=re.IGNORECASE)

if fruit_compile.search(myfavourite):
    match = fruit_compile.search(myfavourite)
    print(match.group())
```

Now using the above I can get the matched string using `match.group()` (which would be `Apples`).

How would I get the matched object as a string from `fruit_compile` (originally `fruit_list`)  (which would be `apple`) without having to iterate back over `fruit_list`?

Comment: Whats your problem. You iterating over `fruit_list` only once without iterating back over.

Comment: The part of the pattern that matched would be `'apples'`, not `'apple'`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you want to *do* with the matching pattern? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

Save the result of `fruit_compile.search(myfavourite)` to a variable.

```
finding = fruit_compile.search(myfavourite)
if finding:
   doSomethingWithFruit(finding.group(0))
```

I noticed you're *already* saving the result of `fruit_compile.search`, but only *after* checking whether the first call returns `None`.

---

You've clarified in a comment that you're looking for the alternative pattern that matched your string.

One way of doing doing it is to find the index of the right alternative by using the `matchObject.groups()`. It's a tuple where every non-matching group is `None`.

Find the index of the non-`None` value and you'll be able to retrieve the right item from your original list of fruits. This obviously involves iterating one way or another, which sort of runs contrary to your last sentence.

You will have to create one group per alternative with this approach.

```
'(' + ')|('.join(fruits) + ')'
```

---

Another option is to use a `for` loop, trying to match the candidates one by one.

```
patterns = [re.compile(p) for p in fruits]
for p in patterns:
  if p.match(string):
    return p.pattern
```

I'm not sure how this affects the overall performance.

**NOTE**: If your 'patterns' are simply constant strings, you shouldn't be using regular expressions in the first place. I'm basing this answer on the assumption that your sample code has been simplified for the sake of clarity.

Comment: This just gets the match.group (from myfavorite), which I already have. I need to know the element in the compiled re object that was matched against the content of myfavorite.

Comment: @devnull You're saying you want the part of the *pattern* that matched the input?

Comment: Hi, yes. So in my application, the fruit_list that is compiled is a list of regex (joined with a bar `|`). When using re.search, I need to get the regex object from the compiled list that matched the provided string. That way I can then perform a lookup as to what action to take when a string matches a specific regex. So far I can only see a way of finding the match, but not the element that was matched against in the compiled object. Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: @devnull Edited

Answer (score 0):

There's a recipe for literally this exact thing in the Python docs page for re:

```
m.string[m.start(g):m.end(g)]
```

Where m is the match object (it would be *match* in your case) and g is the optional group argument.

Comment: Yes, it does not. Because you have no match. You can if the match, try/except or whatever, but that's not what the question was about.

Comment: The OP deals with `None` by calling `search` twice, which is why I suggested saving the result. The question could've been worded better, but I don't think the issue is extracting the matching string. That's exactly what `m.group` does.

Comment: ...what. The 'match' in the code snipped I see here is a variable name that stores the result of a *re.search()* call.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `search`. Edited.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that. Yeah, that's pointless and inefficient, doing the same work twice.

Comment: This is not what I need. I don't want the match[ed] string from myfavourite, I want the match from the compiled object (which is a pattern joined with `|`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<compiled_obj>.pattern`

```
searched_pattern = fruit_compile.pattern
print (searched_pattern)

'apples|banana|peach|plum|pineapple|kiwi'
```

Comment: That's not what I am after. I don't need the whole pattern, but the match within the compiled object.